# SQLite Error 1: no such table: __EFMigrationsHistory

Tags: c#, reactjs, sqlite, entity-framework-core, one-to-many

> SQLite Error 1: no such table: __EFMigrationsHistory

It happens after I migrate and update database. I am using a combination of Entity Framework Core and SQLite and have several `DbSet`s in my `DbContext` file:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using VinylTap.Models;

namespace VinylTap.ClientApp.Data
{
    public class AlbumContext : DbContext
    {
        public AlbumContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AlbumOnHand> AlbumsOnHand { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ConfigurationEntity> Configurations { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<AlbumOnHand>()
                .HasOne(b => b.Album)
                .WithMany(a => a.AlbumsOnHand)
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.AlbumId);
        }
    }
}
```

One to many relationship with album to albums on hand, respectively. `DbInitializer` file :

```
using VinylTap.ClientApp.Data;
using VinylTap.Models;

namespace VinylTap.Data
{
    public static class DbInitializer
    {
        public static void Initialize(AlbumContext context)
        {
            if (context.Albums.Any()) return; //db has been seeded
        }
    }
}
```

One of my principal `Controller` files:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using OAuth;
using Flurl.Http;

namespace VinylTap.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AlbumsController : Controller
    {
        private static string _apiBaseUrl = "https://api.discogs.com/";
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public AlbumsController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet("search")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GeneralSearch(string query)
        {
            // var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"/database/search?query={query}");
            var requestUrl =  _apiBaseUrl + $"database/search?query={query}";

            var client = new OAuthRequest
            {
                Method = "GET",
                Type = OAuthRequestType.ProtectedResource,
                SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.PlainText,
                ConsumerKey = _configuration["CONSUMER_KEY"],
                ConsumerSecret = _configuration["CONSUMER_SECRET"],
                Token = _configuration["OAUTH_TOKEN"],
                TokenSecret = _configuration["OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET"],
                RequestUrl = _apiBaseUrl + $"database/search?query={query}",
            };
            Console.WriteLine(client.GetAuthorizationQuery());
            var url = requestUrl + client.GetAuthorizationQuery();
            var result = await url.GetStringAsync();
            return Ok(result);
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View("Error!");
        }
    }
}
```

I attempted to integrate OAuth 1.0a (not 2.0) authentication for the external API I've planned to use, methods of concealing API tokens (.env), as well as the one-to-many entity relationship.

`ConfigurationsController` (for grabbing API keys from a separate file):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using VinylTap.ClientApp.Data;
using VinylTap.Models;

namespace VinylTap.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/configuration")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ConfigurationsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ConfigurationsController> _logger;
        private readonly AlbumContext _context;

        public ConfigurationsController(ILogger<ConfigurationsController> logger, AlbumContext context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SaveConfiguration([FromBody] ConfigurationModel configuration)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var configEntity = new ConfigurationEntity 
            {
                ConsumerKey = configuration.ConsumerKey,
                ConsumerSecret = configuration.ConsumerSecret,
                OAuthToken = configuration.OAuthToken,
                OAuthTokenSecret = configuration.OAuthTokenSecret
            };

            _context.Configurations.Add(configEntity);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

`EnvFileController` (future implementation for testing .env file where keys are stored is available, then providing an alternate means to enter one's own tokens if not):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace VinylTap.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/envfile")]
    public class EnvFileController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult CheckEnvFile() {
            var envFilePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), ".env");
            bool isEnvFileAvailable = System.IO.File.Exists(envFilePath);

            return Ok(new { isEnvFileAvailable });
        }
    }
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=vinyltap.db"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Extension folder has only ConfigExtensions.cs in it:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration; //rather than "ConfigurationExtensions.cs"

namespace VinylTap.Extensions
{
    public static class ConfigExtensions
    {
        public static IConfigurationBuilder AddDotEnvFile(this IConfigurationBuilder 
        builder) 
        {
            builder.Add(new DotEnvFileSource());
            return builder;
        }
    }

    public class DotEnvFileSource : IConfigurationSource 
    { 
        public IConfigurationProvider Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder) 
        {
            return new DotEnvFileProvider();
        }
    }

    public class DotEnvFileProvider : ConfigurationProvider
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            var envFilePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), ".env");
            if (File.Exists(envFilePath))
            {
                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(envFilePath);
                foreach (var line in lines)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) || line.StartsWith("#"))
                        continue;

                    var parts = line.Split('=', 2);
                    if (parts.Length == 2)
                    {
                        Data[parts[0]] = parts[1];
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("No .env file found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs (ASP.NET Core 7.0):

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using VinylTap.Extensions;
using System.Reflection;
//using OAuth;
using VinylTap.ClientApp.Data;

var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Development";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.Sources.Clear();

builder.Configuration
    .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()!)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddDotEnvFile();

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AlbumContext>(options => {
    options.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "OAuth";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "OAuth";
});
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Where is your Program.cs or Startup.cs file, can you post how it looks like?

Comment: Program.cs added (no Startup.cs, it's post-5.0)

Comment: I had a similar issue wherr this error was being cased by the connection string not being in the json file but yours looks okay. The connection string is in the json file and also added to Program.cs

Comment: Yeah idk. It was working before I introduced some of the "Configuration" extension and controller stuff. Also I've been wondering if the prepackaged React project template in VS2022 is to blame. It was making a lot of noise about React versions not being the latest whenever I tried to npm install something new. Plus there's all of this extra bloat that comes with it in VS. Guess there's always some wrangling involved with getting dotnet core and react to coexist in the same proj no matter how you approach it.

Comment: Yes did you try implementing the changes in my answer to see if it would resolve the issue.

Comment: The Controllers and react packages shouldn't affect the database creation. Your seeing that error becsus the database file cannot be found. That's why we need to resolve the issue. The table exists by default when a new database file is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a Configuration Builder class to build the configuration and the use that configuration to get the Connection String and then also remove the line `builder.Configuration.Sources.Clear()` as it could be clearing the connection string from your configuration file.

```
//build your configuration like this
var cfg = new ConfigurationBuilder()
         .SetBasePath(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath)
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json",optional: false,reloadOnChange: true)
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json",optional: true)
.AddEnvironmentVariables()
.Build();
//then use the configuration to use sqlite 
options.UseSqlite(cfg.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
```

Also when you have updated the definitions for the Entity class that map to your table and you need to create a new migration file then it would be advisable to remove the current migration file using the command

> dotnet ef migrations remove

Delete the old database and then add a new migration with the command

> dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate

Open your Nuget Package manager console and run the `Update-Database` command to complete the process.
However before you do this, you need to back up user data somewhere so you can insert into the new table.

Comment: Awesome! Initial signs indicate that `builder.Configuration.Sources.Clear()` was the culprit.

Comment: Your welcome, I also suspected that line was clearing some of the strings you have defined in your json file. Thanks also for accepting my answer.

Comment: It's such a specific oversight on my part. Hoping this thread has some relevance for others nonetheless. You're the man vw

Comment: Your welcome, its gonna save a lot of future visitors. Thanks for the kind words.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give permission to access __EFMigrationsHistory table for the user. You can pass the user's username and password in the connection string. I believe you can do this using database manager as well.

Comment: Thanks for that. Since this issue arose, I have not been able to generate a database at all, so there is nothing to go and grant permission *to. I should note, also, that an earlier version of this project (w/ only Album and AlbumOnHand) was migrating and updating correctly. Also, what username and password would that be? I don't recall having to do that before.